# Variables values don't get out from DoInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Someone could please explain me why the value of the variable `picture` is present only in the `OnInBackground()`?

When I access it in the `OnPostExecute` the value is lost.

```
public class GetPostAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{

    String picture="";

    public GetPostAsync(Context context){
        c=context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute (){
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        try {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/myquery",
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jobj = response.getJSONObject();
                                picture = jobj.getString("picture");

                                Log.i("TEST","pic: "+picture);  //return the right value
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        return picture;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("TEST","pic: "+picture);  //return empty 
    }
}
```

I have declare `picture` on Top of the Activity. I don't know how keep the values that I retrieve in the `Onbackground()`

Comment: you don't have to return the value in `doInBackground` because it's already in a global var in the inner class. Just change this `AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>` to this `AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>`

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwanplease learn some java's basics...  It is not global variable but field

Comment: It's mutltithreading...  request.executeAsync(); http://ideone.com/PPHi95

Comment: field:
A data member of a class. Unless specified otherwise, a field is not static.

Comment: variable:
An item of data named by an identifier. Each variable has a type, such as int or Object, and a scope. See also class variable, instance variable, local variable.

Comment: I called it a `global variable` because I was looking at the inner class as a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `request.executeAsync` from `doInBackground`. Therefore, `doInBackground` will return immediately and `onPostExecute` may be called before your `onCompleted` callback is called.